Trying to open a sqlplus file via a python script is giving an error "SP2-0310: unable to open file". The file opens correctly when not using python
I am using
import os

# Specify the directory you want to change to, take input from keyboard
directory_path = r"C:\code\xyz\deployment\tbd\example"

# Change the directory
os.chdir(directory_path)

to adjust the path to my .sql file
then I am running a simple subprocess function
def execute_sqlplus_command(command):
    """Executes a SQL*Plus command and returns the output."""

    session = subprocess.Popen(
        ["sqlplus", "-S", "test/password@database"],
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    )

    sql_command = command.encode() + b";\n"
    stdout, stderr = session.communicate(sql_command)

    return stdout.decode(), stderr.decode()

and using these sql commands
# calls for running script
command = "set role l;"
output, error = execute_sqlplus_command(command)

command = r"@l.sql;"
output, error = execute_sqlplus_command(command)

The first "set role l" runs, but the call "@l.sql;" produces the error
Output: SP2-0310: unable to open file "l.sql;"

Running the "@l.sql;" in sqlplus runs fine and works.
Ive tried a more specific path to the exact folder and it wont open.
Ive checked and changed the privacy settings to the sql file.

The folder itself contains 2 sqlcalls, but I wanted to keep it a little more ambiguous because im writing a script that will run hundreds of files with this same name.
Am I doing something wrong in the python script?

perhaps it's the double semicolon since the function terminates the command with b";\n" and command = r"@lsdba.sql;" has another one.

Popen takes a cwd parameter, I would use that instead of os.chdir
